# compute.instances.host Error an instance during

Tags: google-compute-engine

In the operations history of my compute engine project, my machines all have an operation listed as "Automatically migrate an instance (compute.instances.automaticRestart)". They are all on the same zone, using the same debian template.

I suppose that their was some maintenance on the plateform, which is fine for me if the OS doesn't reboot.

Unfortunately two machines suffered a reboot. The operations history listed the operation as  "compute.instances.hostError an instance" (compute.instances.hostError). 
In addition Syslog doesn't suggest a clean shutdown.

Is there anything I should/can do to prevent such problem?

edit : We are europe-west1-b and all servers have the setting : On host maintenance to Migrate VM instance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't look like this was ever answered.

compute.instances.hostError means there was a hardware or software failure on the physical machine that was hosting your VM.

The FAQ has a description -- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/zones#maintenance) article all the zones in GCE except "europe-west1-a" have Transparent maintenance where the instance will be live migrated without rebooting it. If your instance is in a zone with Transparent Maintenance you can set the option **On host maintenance** to **Migrate VM instance** using your developer console. Once this option is set your instance will be live migrated without rebooting the instance.

Comment: We are not on europe-west1-a and the On host maintenance to Migrate VM instance is enabled on all servers

Comment: In that case as per the documentation you will receive the notification about the maintenance two week in advance and you need to migrate those instances manually to other zones. In order to take advantage of live migration I would recommend creating instances in zones transparent migration enabled.

Comment: There was no maintenance scheduled, and the zone we are in (west1-b, we choosed specificaly because no maintenance where planned) has transparent migration enabled

Comment: I am sorry i misunderstood you last reply(I thought your instance was in europe-west1-a). It is possible for you to attach the screenshot from developer console of operation page with the error message. And also can you copy the syslog which shows the error message related to instance reboot after maintenance.

Comment: Hi sorry, for the reply delay. The syslog doesn't give an error. The absence of message indicating a clean shutdown before some lines indicating a OS startup tell me there has probably been a hardreboot. The syslogs have been rotated anyway, and as for the errors, they have disapeared from the operation history... but I'm still interested to know what I could do about this